# Login with gmail api in my website in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I have to add the functionality of login with gmail account on my website. Users only with my domain should be validated and users trying to login with other domain should be redirected to google login page and shown an message. If user logs in successfully via gmail then he should also get logged in into membership table. How to do this in asp.net. Here is my code:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        var OAUTHURL = 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?';
        var VALIDURL = 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo?access_token=';
        var SCOPE = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email';
        var CLIENTID = '7480000038683-rhs9hdsc31uu2avuq8avlsed5i7hk.apps.googleusercontent.com';
        var REDIRECT = 'http://localhost:0000/default.aspx?company=xyz';
        var LOGOUT = 'http://accounts.google.com/Logout';
        var TYPE = 'token';
        var HD = "ranosys.com";
        var _url = OAUTHURL + 'scope=' + SCOPE + '&client_id=' + CLIENTID + '&redirect_uri=' + REDIRECT + '&response_type=' + TYPE + '&login_hint=' + LOGINHINT + '&hd='+ HD;
        var acToken;
        var tokenType;
        var expiresIn;
        var user;
        var hd;
        var loggedIn = false;
        function login() {
            var win = window.open(_url,"_self");
            var pollTimer = window.setInterval(function () {
                try {
                    console.log(win.document.URL);
                    if (win.document.URL.indexOf(REDIRECT) != -1) {
                        window.clearInterval(pollTimer);
                        var url = win.document.URL;
                        acToken = gup(url, 'access_token');
                        tokenType = gup(url, 'token_type');
                        expiresIn = gup(url, 'expires_in');

                        win.close();
                        validateToken(acToken);
                    }
                }
                catch (e) {
                }
            }, 500);
        }
        function validateToken(token) {
            $.ajax(
                {
                    url: VALIDURL + token,
                    data: null,
                    success: function (responseText) {
                        getUserInfo();
                        loggedIn = true;
                        $('#loginText').hide();
                        $('#logoutText').show();
                    },
                    dataType: "jsonp"
                });
        }
        function getUserInfo() {

            debugger;
            $.ajax({
                url: 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo?access_token=' + acToken,
                data: null,
                success: function (resp) {
                    user = resp;
                    var email = user.email;
                    alert(email);
                    console.log(user);
                    $('#uName').text('Welcome ' + user.name);
                    $('#imgHolder').attr('src', user.picture);
                },
                dataType: "jsonp"
            });
        }
        //credits: http://www.netlobo.com/url_query_string_javascript.html  

        function gup(url, name) {
            namename = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\\]");
            var regexS = "[\\#&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)";
            var regex = new RegExp(regexS);
            var results = regex.exec(url);
            if (results == null)
                return "";
            else
                return results[1];
        }
        function startLogoutPolling() {
            $('#loginText').show();
            $('#logoutText').hide();
            loggedIn = false;
            $('#uName').text('Welcome ');
            $('#imgHolder').attr('src', 'none.jpg');
        }
</script>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow , and Post your code what you tried so far ?

Comment: I used javascript code to solve it and used hd parameter to restrict it with my domain only. It worked well but didnt show any message to the user attempting login with different domains.It neither logged in valid users to membership table.Here is my code

Answer (score 0):

You need the lastest JQuery like this

Follow the last example here : http://www.gethugames.in/blog/2012/04/authentication-and-authorization-for-google-apis-in-javascript-popup-window-tutorial.html

This is my code working

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"
    type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>
        var OAUTHURL    =   'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?';
        var VALIDURL    =   'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo?access_token=';
        var SCOPE       =   'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email';
        var CLIENTID    =   '716569014051.apps.googleusercontent.com';
        var REDIRECT    =   'http://www.gethugames.in/proto/googleapi/oauth/'
        var LOGOUT      =   'http://accounts.google.com/Logout';
        var TYPE        =   'token';
        var _url        =   OAUTHURL + 'scope=' + SCOPE + '&client_id=' + CLIENTID + '&redirect_uri=' + REDIRECT + '&response_type=' + TYPE;
        var acToken;
        var tokenType;
        var expiresIn;
        var user;
        var loggedIn    =   false;

        function login() {
            var win         =   window.open(_url, "windowname1", 'width=800, height=600'); 

            var pollTimer   =   window.setInterval(function() { 
                try {
                    console.log(win.document.URL);
                    if (win.document.URL.indexOf(REDIRECT) != -1) {
                        window.clearInterval(pollTimer);
                        var url =   win.document.URL;
                        acToken =   gup(url, 'access_token');
                        tokenType = gup(url, 'token_type');
                        expiresIn = gup(url, 'expires_in');
                        win.close();

                        validateToken(acToken);
                    }
                } catch(e) {
                }
            }, 500);
        }

        function validateToken(token) {
            $.ajax({
                url: VALIDURL + token,
                data: null,
                success: function(responseText){  
                    getUserInfo();
                    loggedIn = true;
                    $('#loginText').hide();
                    $('#logoutText').show();
                },  
                dataType: "jsonp"  
            });
        }

        function getUserInfo() {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo?access_token=' + acToken,
                data: null,
                success: function(resp) {
                    user    =   resp;
                    console.log(user);
                    $('#uName').text('Welcome ' + user.name);
                    $('#imgHolder').attr('src', user.picture);
                },
                dataType: "jsonp"
            });
        }

        //credits: http://www.netlobo.com/url_query_string_javascript.html
        function gup(url, name) {
            name = name.replace(/[\[]/,"\\\[").replace(/[\]]/,"\\\]");
            var regexS = "[\\#&]"+name+"=([^&#]*)";
            var regex = new RegExp( regexS );
            var results = regex.exec( url );
            if( results == null )
                return "";
            else
                return results[1];
        }

        function startLogoutPolling() {
            $('#loginText').show();
            $('#logoutText').hide();
            loggedIn = false;
            $('#uName').text('Welcome ');
            $('#imgHolder').attr('src', 'none.jpg');
        }

    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <a href='#' onClick='login();' id="loginText"'> Click here to login </a>
    <a href="#" style="display:none" id="logoutText" target='myIFrame' onclick="myIFrame.location='https://www.google.com/accounts/Logout'; startLogoutPolling();return false;"> Click here to logout </a>
    <iframe name='myIFrame' id="myIFrame" style='display:none'></iframe>
    <div id='uName'></div>
    <img src='' id='imgHolder'/>
</body>
</html>
```